# MongoDB duplicate key error in collection when registering users for appointments

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm trying to register users for an appointment and even though all the users have different emails and ID's I'm still getting this error: `Error creating appointment: MongoServerError: E11000 duplicate key error collection: test.appointments index: user.Email_1 dup key: { user.Email: null }`

Here's the code:

AppointmentModel.js:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const UserModel = require("./UserModel").schema;
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const AppointmentSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  title: {
    type: String,
    unique: false
  },

  Date: {
    type: Date,
    unique: true
  },
  Time: {
    type: String,
    unique: true
  },
  userEmail: {
    type: String,
    ref: "User"
  }
});

const appointment = mongoose.model("Appointment", AppointmentSchema);
module.exports = appointment;
```

UserModel.js:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

let errorInfo;
let pattern;

let validateEmail = (email) => {
    pattern = new RegExp(/^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|.(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/);
    errorInfo = "Please enter a valid email address"
    return pattern.test(email);
}

let validatePassword = (password) => {
    pattern = new RegExp("^(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*?[0-9])(?=.*?[#?!@$ %^&*-]).{8,}$");
    errorInfo = "Password should contain at least 8 characters, one special character and one uppercase letter"
    return pattern.test(password);
}

const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    Username: {
        type: String,
        required: "Username cannot be empty",
        trim: true,
        unique: "That username is already taken"

    },
    Email: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      trim: true,
      unique: true,
      sparse: true,
      validate: [validateEmail, "Please enter a valid email address"],
    },
    Password: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        trim: true,
        validate: [validatePassword, errorInfo]
    }
});

const user = mongoose.model("User", UserSchema);
module.exports = user;
```

index.js:

```
app.post("/createAppointment", async (req, res) => {
  const username = req.body.username;
  const date = req.body.date;
  const time = req.body.time;
  const title = req.body.appointmentTitle;

  try {
    
    const user = await UserModel.findOne({ Username: username });

    if (!user) {
      // If user not found, return an error
      return res.status(404).json({ error: "User not found" });
    }

    
    const newAppointment = new AppointmentModel({
      title: title,
      Date: date,
      Time: time,
      userEmail: user.Email
    });

   
    await newAppointment.save();
    console.log("Appointment created successfully");
    res.status(200).json({ message: "Appointment created successfully" });
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(`Error creating appointment: ${err}`);
    res.status(500).json({ error: "Error creating appointment" });
  }
});
```

Tried using the user's ID, didn't work
Tried using chatgpt, obviously didn't work,
Tried removing every unique property also didn't work